# REST api cacheablity with authorization

Tags: api, rest, caching, authorization

I'm building a protected api for a web application.
for each web service call client sends an access token.
when call for a resource depending on the access token it returns different responses.
    ex:- call to /employees will return accessible employees only. accessibility will be defined for each access token.
my question is how it's possible to cache the response if it's returned different things depend on the access token.
is the access token part of the request which is considered in caching?
can the API be REST if it's not cacheable?
is partial access to resource allowed in REST?

Answer (score -1):

@DamithK please clear what you want to do i am not getting it.."when call for a resource depending on the access token it returns different responses.
But as much i understand is that you want to authenticate your each api call.
If you are using RestClient for call api you can do it in following way.To call Api

```
var client = new RestClient(Serviceurl);
        var request = new RestRequest("/Apimethod/{Inputs}?oauth_consumer_key=1ece74e1ca9e4befbb1b64daba7c4a24", Method.GET);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

In your service

```
public static class Authentication
{
    public static bool AuthenticateRequest(IncomingWebRequestContext context)
    {
        bool Authenticated = false;
        try
        {
            NameValueCollection param = context.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters;
            if (param != null && param["oauth_consumer_key"] != null)
            {
                string consumerSecretKey = "1ece74e1ca9e4befbb1b64daba7c4a24";
                Authenticated = param["oauth_consumer_key"] == consumerSecretKey;
            }
            else
            {
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        return Authenticated;
    }
}
```

Validate each request in called method using

```
Authentication.AuthenticateRequest(WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest)
```

All this is c# code

Comment: Thanks for answering. my problem is not with authentication but the authorization.
different access tokens will have different permissions.
so the response may not return full employee list for some access tokens. only the accessible employees will be returned.

Comment: Means you want to filter employee list using token.This is depends on you how you want implement that logic.According me what you can do Store all tokens into DB and map every employee to specific token and when you get that token in request you can filter employee based on token.And let me know if you have any idea.